# How can I install the Dracula theme for Ubuntu on Windows 10?

Tags: themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I love the [Dracula theme](https://github.com/dracula/dracula-theme) and it's available for Windows terminal, but I'm not sure what the Ubuntu terminal for WSL is using. How can I install a theme file for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot install Dracula theme into Bash for Windows shell directly, but you can install ZSH shell with [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) in WSL and then install Dracula to it.

Open WSL shell and follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install -y zsh git curl
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Add the following lines into ~/.bashrc file (`nano ~/.bashrc`) to start ZSH shell on WSL open:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
exec zsh
fi
```

Then you can follow the [Dracula installation steps](https://draculatheme.com/zsh/):

```
git clone https://github.com/dracula/zsh.git
ln -s ~/zsh/dracula.zsh-theme ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/dracula.zsh-theme
```

Configure ZSH (`nano ~/.zshrc`) and edit the following line

```
ZSH_THEME="dracula"
```

However, you have to also install fonts to display ZSH correctly in WSL, see steps in Oh My ZSH section here: https://github.com/bootstraponline/meta/wiki/Windows_10_Bash

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline
```

You can download ConEmu here: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu or you can use Windows Terminal (Preview) from Microsoft store instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write that out. Welcome to stack exchange!

Comment: Oh, you're not new. It said New Contributor. Well, welcome to Ubuntu.SE anyway!

Comment: I'm glad I could be helpful